# Why is css styling <P> in an <A> when told not to

Tags: css

This made me royally confused about the `:not()` selector, because the behavior is the same cross-browser:

CSS:

```css
main *:not(a) p {
    color: red;
}
a {
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<main>
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" alt="640x480"/>
            <figcaption>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                   Donec hendrerit dolor mattis rutrum condimentum.</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <p>Cras non felis <a href="http://google.com">venenatis, venenatis</a>
       elit quis, rutrum tortor.</p>
</main>
```

SSCCE: http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/SmLWS/1/

Cross browser, this styles the `<A>` in the `<P>` blue, but the `<P>` in the `<A>` red. `<FIGURE>` used as an example of why I want this to work.

Comment: What are you confused about? `figure` and `figcaption` are essentially `:not(a)` so it matches the first rule.

Comment: What color do you expect the `<P>` in the `<A>` to be?

Comment: @wdosanjos I expect the `<P>` to inherit is color from `<A>`, because I don't expect `main *:not(a) p` to match a `<P>` inside an `<A>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main *:not(a) p` does not mean "`<p>`, a descendant of `<main>`, with no `<a>` anywhere in between".  It means "`<p>`, a descendant of *something which is not `<a>`*, which is a descendant of `<main>`".

So, for instance, it will not match `<main><a><p>...</p></a></main>`, because the only thing in between the `<main>` and the `<p>` is the `<a>`, and it won't match `<main><p>...</p></main>` either, because there is *nothing* in between `<main>` and `<p>`.  But it *will* match `<main><figure><a><p>...</a></figure></main>`, because the descendant combinator allows the `*:not(a)` to skip the `<a>` and bind to the `<figure>`.

**EDIT:** Forget the nasty thing I suggested before, I *think* this does what you want:

```css
p      { color: red }
a, a p { color: blue }
```

When an `<a>` is inside a `<p>`, blue wins because the `<a>` is the nearest ancestor that set the color.  When a `<p>` is inside an `<a>`, blue wins because `a p` is more specific than just `p`.

Comment: Thanks for being fast and preventing me to write an engrish version of the same answer :D

Comment: +1 for being fast, accurate, and apologizing for the silly required selector

Comment: @Supuhstar I thought of a better way to do what you want (assuming I understood what you want).